# Docker compose application has not public ports on digitalocean

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I have docker compose web app:

```
version: '3.3'

services: 
  app:
    image: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    restart: always 
    network_mode: 'host'
```

- image is hidden because of private code

After startup I can call `wget http://localhost:4004` on server but once I call `PUBLICIP:4004` it doesnt wor, looks like port is not accesable. Firawall is disabled. I am using ubuntu.

Is there any wrong with docker compose?

I tried to google and SO

Comment: You shouldn't usually need to disable Docker networking with `network_mode: host`...but beyond that, there's not really enough detail here to say more.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Is this a programming question, or more about the deployment mechanics?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish only port add ports key:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app:
    image: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ports:
      - "4004:4004"
```

You can read more here:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Probably you will be interested in connecting it to domain and securing by ssl. I recommend you check `nginx-proxy-automation`.

https://github.com/evertramos/nginx-proxy-automation

I appending below example from my production that works with this library

```
version: '3'

services:
  gql:
    image: registry.digitalocean.com/main/xue-gql
    ports:
      - ${DOCKER_PORT}:4000
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${HOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${HOST}
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=${DOCKER_PORT}
    command: node ./src/index.js

  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ${NETWORK:-proxy}
```